# How can I change a background below date part and an icon of datepicker button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

Here is how it looks right now:[image]

What I've tried here is to edit templates, on date and template on button also, and I get this code after I followed next steps:

> Right click on DatePicker -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy

But I don't know where and what I should change to change an default icon and default background below date part...

```
<Style x:Key="MyDatePickerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#D9D9D9" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                                    <Border.Background>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Border.Background>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                                <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1"  Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{DynamicResource MyButtonTemplateDatePicker}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                                <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#D9D9D9" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#D9D9D9" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19"/>
                                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplateDatePicker" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                    <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                        <Rectangle.Stroke>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Stroke>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                    <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Thanks guys and cheers!

Comment: Which background are you referring to? The gray one?

Answer (score 0):

The calendar icon is defined in the "MyButtonTemplateDatePicker" `ControlTemplate`. It's made up by a bunch of `Border` elements, a `Rectangle` and a `Path`.

You change the icon by modifying this template. You may for example replace the `Path` with your own custom one. Of course this requires you to actually define an `Path` that displays your custom icon.